# Fixing Dash in Words When Iterating in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor, angular-template

I have to iterate non-product in *ngFor but it doesnt accept the -
It can only accept _ but in -

How would you be able to fix this?

```
*ngFor="let product of products?.non-product
```

Comment: You can not use dot notation for illegal identifiers, use `[]` notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) since key property name is not a valid [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/identifier).

```
*ngFor="let product of products['non-product']"
```

Comment: And because now `?` operator is not being used, you can use the ternary operator to be safe:- `*ngFor="let product of (products ? products['non-product']: [])"`